# How can I populate a google maps info window with text from a jQuery ajax request? [example included]

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here I make an ajax request and process it in order to return a paragraph of text. I would like to populate my info window with this text on a 'click' event.

My code functions in so far as the ajax call is successful and the map and markers are rendered in the View. However, the info window does not populate with the text on the 'click' event as I had hoped.

Instead I get a type error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'function (){
                wikiExtract(marker.title).then(function (data){
                infowindow...<omitted>... }' of undefined
```

**If I try another pattern that seems intuitively correct to me, the map will not load at all**:

```
google.maps.event.addListener('click',
    wikiExtract(marker.title).then(function (data){
        infowindow.setContent(data);
        infowindow.open(bayarea, marker)
    });
);
```

This is my map and ajax call:

```
'use strict';

var bayarea;
var markers = [];

var initMap = function() {
    const map = document.querySelector('#map');
    const center = {
        lat: 37.656,
        lng: -122.288
    };

    bayarea = new google.maps.Map(map, {
        center,
        zoom: 9,
        scrollwheel: false,
    });

    var getMarkers = function getMarkers(siteDatabase) {
        var i = 1;
        for (var site in siteDatabase) {
            site = siteDatabase[site];
            addMarker(site, i * 200);
            i++;
        };

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        function addMarker(site, timeout) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(site.lat, site.lng),
                    map: bayarea,
                    title: site.position,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener('click',function (){
                    wikiExtract(marker.title).then(function (data){
                    infowindow.setContent(data);
                    infowindow.open(bayarea, marker);
                    });

                });
                markers.push(marker);
            }, timeout);
        }    
    };
    getMarkers(siteDatabase);
};

function wikiExtract(site) {
    return $.when(ventanaWik(site)).then( (wiki) => {
        return dig(wiki.query.pages).extract;
    });
    function dig(object) {
        return object[Object.keys(object)[0]];
    }
    function ventanaWik(site) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'json',
            url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php' + '?origin=*'
            + '&format=json' + '&action=query' + '&prop=extracts'
            + '&exintro=' + '&explaintext=' + '&titles=' + site,
            method: 'GET'
        }).promise();
    }
};
```

EDIT: Works using this pattern

```
   var initMap = function() {
    const map = document.querySelector('#map');
    const center = {
        lat: 37.656,
        lng: -122.288
    };

    bayarea = new google.maps.Map(map, {
        center,
        zoom: 9,
        scrollwheel: false,
    });

    var getMarkers = function getMarkers(siteDatabase) {
        var i = 1;
        for (var site in siteDatabase) {
            site = siteDatabase[site];
            addMarker(site, i * 200);
            i++;
        }

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg' style='color: #FFA46B;' title='Loading...'></i> Loading..."
        });

        function addMarker(site, timeout) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(site.lat, site.lng),
                    map: bayarea,
                    title: site.position,
                    county: site.county,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infowindow) {
                return function() {
                    if (infowindow) {
                        infowindow.close();
                    }
                    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                    setTimeout(function(){ marker.setAnimation(null); }, 1500);
                    infowindow.open(bayarea, marker);
                    wikiExtract(marker.title).then(function(data) {
                        infowindow.setContent(data);
                    });
                };
            })(marker, infowindow));
            markers.push(marker);
            }, timeout);
        }    
    };
    getMarkers(siteDatabase);
};

function wikiExtract(site) {
    return $.when(ventanaWik(site)).then( (wiki) => {
        return dig(wiki.query.pages).extract;
    });
    function dig(object) {
        return object[Object.keys(object)[0]];
    }
    function ventanaWik(site) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'json',
            url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php' + '?origin=*'
            + '&format=json' + '&action=query' + '&prop=extracts'
            + '&exintro=' + '&explaintext=' + '&titles=' + site,
            method: 'GET'
        }).promise();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation google.maps.event.addListener() has 3 parameters: instance:Object, eventName:string, handler:Function.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

You are missing the first parameter:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (){
    wikiExtract(marker.title).then(function (data){
        infowindow.setContent(data);
        infowindow.open(bayarea, marker);
    });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately that does not work. I need geocodezip to share his wisdom.

Comment: I got it to work following the pattern I will add above